# Geometric mean proof with two tangents

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

There are two tangent lines on $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ each with the $x$-value $a$ and $b$ respectively.

I need to prove that $c$, the $x$ value of the point at which the two lines intersect each other, is equal to $\sqrt{ab}$, the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$.

I have been trying many different ways of doing this question and I keep getting stuck.

Comment: Hint: the curve is a parabola

Comment: @TBrendle Thanks but I am not sure that will help me, the problem I am having with this is the algebra, I know to take the derivative and use that in the point slope equation for both a and b, make both sides equal to each other and solve for x. The issue is solving for x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two points of tangency are $(a, \sqrt{a})$ and $(b, \sqrt{b})$. If either of $a$ or $b$ is $0$ then the result holds trivially, so assume $ab \neq 0$.

Because the curve is a parabola, the intersection of the tangents, $(x_0, y_0)$, has $y_0=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})/2$. That's because projecting perpendicularly onto the directrix, the intersection of two tangents of a parabola will always bisect the segment between the points of tangency (draw a picture). This can be proved using high school geometry and is sometimes known as the Two-Tangent Theorem for the parabola.

The equation for the tangent at $(a, \sqrt{a})$ is 
$$y- \sqrt{a}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}(x-a) .
$$
This line passes through $(x_0, y_0)$ so we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{2} - \sqrt{a}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}(x_0-a).
$$
Simplifying,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}}{2} =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}(x_0-a).
$$
Clearing denominators gives
$$
\sqrt{ab}-a = x_0 -a,
$$
and so $x_0= \sqrt{ab}$, as desired.

**Notice**: In fact, if $A$ and $B$ are distinct non-zero points on the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $C$ is the intersection of the tangents at $A$ and $B$, then we have

> the $x$-coordinate of C is the *geometric* mean of the $x$-coordinates of $A$ and $B$

and

> the $y$-coordinate of C is the *arithmetic* mean of the $y$-coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

The tangent line at $(a,\sqrt{a})$ has equation $y=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}x+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$.

The tangent line at $(b,\sqrt{b})$ has equation $y=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}}x+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{2}$.

Set $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}x+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}}x+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{2}$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: Why is the last fraction divided by two? What I had was very similar except the last fraction wasn't divided by two.

Comment: The equation of the first tangent line has shape $y=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}x+k$. Put $x=a$. We must have $y=\sqrt{a}$. Thus $\sqrt{a}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}a+k=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}+k$. That gives $k=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}$.